# t-sql INSERT statement. What do I edit

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

When inserting values into my table what do I edit here? 
Do I delete the "<" or everything each side of the comma and then just enter what values belong?

```
  INSERT INTO .[place]
       ([plcName]
       ,[plcCode]
       ,[plcVat]
       ,[plccurc]
       ,[plcLive]
       ,[plcISOCodeNumeric]
       ,[plcTRSEnabled])
 VALUES
       (<plcName, char(15),>
       ,<plcCode, char(2),>
       ,<plcVat, char(1),>
       ,<plccurc, char(1),>
       ,<plcLive, char(1),>
       ,<plcISOCodeNumeric, char(3),>
       ,<plcTRSEnabled, bit,>)
```

GO

Comment: i do not see why this garnered a downvote its a toally legitimate question asked by a clear beginner. I would suggest if someone answers this question that you accept the answer also.

Comment: Thanks Krystan.. Just started with a new DB so don't want to make any mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the values in the `<>` are what needs editing

example

```
 INSERT INTO .[Country]
       ([plcName]
       ,[plcCode]
       ,[plcVat]
       ,[plccurc]
       ,[plcLive]
       ,[plcISOCodeNumeric]
       ,[plcTRSEnabled])
 VALUES 
       ('thename', 
       ,'cd'
       ,'y' 
       ,'x' 
       ,'1' 
       ,'123'
       ,1)
```

Comment: As in change 
 <cyName, char(15),>
to
<Nigeria, char(15),>
??

Answer (score 4):

This looks like it was generated in SQL Server Management Studio.

In SSMS, `<name, type,>` patterns are used in templates for quickly adding values.

Hold down <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and you'll get a dialog window asking you to specify values

Comment: Excellent.. Thank you kindly.. Any other handy shortcuts I should know?!

Comment: @RoRy Theres a fair few here :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Replace each `<name, type,>` with the corresponsing value. The brackets, name & datatype are just displayed there as hints for you.

```
VALUES
(
  'some litteral value',
  1235,
  6789
)
```